# Does anyone write books on analyzing ( or reviewing) Hinduism?

Tags: puranas, history

Did any non-Hindu write any analysis (review) of Hinduism about why Vedas said like this and why our Puranas said like that etc?

The concepts in our Vedas and Puranas are far away from reality, so there must be some circumstances for people to believe the concepts in Vedas and Puranas.

Not all the people went into deep meditation state and learnt Vedas right? They learnt from Rishis who declared themselves as they went into deep meditation and learnt about Vedas. Then did they directly go to the people and explained what they learnt?

Or else Rishis tried to say something, but as people did not understand, so they come up with some easy superstitious stories for people to understand?  and now they are looking unbelievable to people like me in 21st century?

For example, if a person who lived some 3000 years ago went to another person and said that the ball that we see in night sky is not just moon, but it is a person called "moon god", then what could be the basis for that person to simply believe that concept? ( he will definitely ask how you are saying it right instead of simply believing whoever says whatever right)

Another person says that the cash in your hand is not just cash, it is goddess Laxmi Devi and she looks very similar to moon god means it looks completely strange for a person who listens those sentences very first time. There must be some proof shown for people to believe them. It simply looks strange that if someone says I have seen a goddess in place of cash on my deep meditation state right?

Is there something that the people of that time did not understand the inner meaning and came up with different superstitious stories to penetrate the thoughts into people's brains? On the other hand, not just Puranas, but how come mantras, Stotras, Suktas also will say that moon god is brother of Laxmi goddess? If we assume that the Puranas are some stories for people to understand the concept of god, then there is no problem as we can treat them as just stories for people entertainment just like movie stories, but how come mantras also say the same meaning ( mantras are designed to provide results to those who chants them, they are not like Puranas which are stories for people to make understand the Hinduism concepts, they must have correct truth information as they are supposed to give gifts upon saying them and cannot give if they have wrong information).

I am combining real world history during Vedic period and Hinduism, but not the spiritual world or the history that we see inside our mythologies.

History in Puranas talks about world which is 432000 years back, in Threthayuga, there lives Rama, Sita etc., I am not talking about that history, I am talking about the current history that was proven to be existent by our scientists.

Sorry if my post is vast and not understandable,  I tried my best to make things clear, but please edit if anything is not clear.

Comment: I think you are asking for a book which criticize Hinduism. If so than read:- Kaya baloo ki bheet par khada hai Hindu dharmhttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.in/Bheet-Khada-Dharam-Surender-Sharma/dp/8179874664&ved=2ahUKEwiz187Up7_pAhUQWCsKHT7jBLsQFjABegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw3shU_C1wTCG--UGti_LN8P

Comment: I am looking for how to think in order to understand that the concepts in our religion are correct, but not to prove that these concepts are wrong.

Comment: "There must be some proof shown for people to believe them" - why do you think so? Evidence-based reasoning is a relatively modern development. Taking the word of authority figures as gospel used to be the norm previously

Comment: Or else could someone suggest free advaita online books in telugu to read

Comment: Do you think doubts trying to make sense of supernatural events mentioned in our scriptures were highlighted for the first time in 20th century or when Islam/Christianity came to India or when renaissance revolution took place in Europe ? People have been asking this for thousand of years. You can do search for Charvakas , nastikas out of India. And then when you have read their philosophy then also understand they got subsumed into the fold .

Comment: I found this useful link https://www.advaita-vision.org/materialist-view-of-consciousness/

Comment: @user2225190 - That's great. Glad to be of assistance. And try not to conflate science with scientific community . For a long time , and even now they claim bronze age started 7000 yrs ago. This despite having evidence of lion-man excavated in Germany , said to be 50000 yrs old. So science will keep have new findings. But scientific community is not transparent .

Comment: Are you looking for books like this: [Retrieval of History from Purāṇic Myths](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/retrieval-of-history-from-puranic-myths-IDD200/)? Or why people invented all the mythological stories? You do understand that a lot of Hindus take all these stories literally?